# Can I send private message to my users using PHP Facebook SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I would create a Facebook application and I need to know if I can send private message to the users have joined my application. Is this possible?

*Note: I only would like to send messages **TO MY** users and **NOT** to the friends of my users (I think this is not possible for spam reason...right?).*

Comment: Read [Facebook message API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/)

Comment: @Svetlio It seems to be possible, if you post the answer i will accept it :)

Comment: Its not answer so no need to accept :) Just remember to search for it 1st and then to ask :)

Comment: @Svetlio excuse me, I am reading bjelli answer, and it seems to be not possible....do you confirm that i can send message to my user? i do not understand it, can I or not?

Comment: Check this - [Stackoverflow Question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Comment: @Svetlio pardon, I see many answer but many of those are deprecated. Maybe sending an email to user@facebook.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASAIK you cannot just send a message, but you can open a dialog for the user to see + send a message:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

[image: send dialog]

(via http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

Comment: wait i think this dialog is useful to send message TO the user's friends, no? As I wrote in the question, I only would like to send a private message TO MY user (read: to the users have joined my application, not to their friends)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API has something called [App Notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/). It is still in beta but working very nice.

Comment: yes I read about notification. It is useful but I would like to send messages to the user's inbox. Possible? do i have to send email to user@facebook.com ?

Comment: read_mailbox give you only read access; [source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to a mailbox. Facebook a couple of years ago allowed access to send messages, but they realized very quickly how easily this is abused.